# dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password rake aborted

Tags: rake, redmine, rdoc, dpkg

I'm trying to install redmine on ubuntu server and when I use the following command :

apt-get install redmine redmine-mysql

I get the following informations :

```
Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
redmine est déjà la plus récente version disponible.
redmine-mysql est déjà la plus récente version disponible.
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 36 non mis à jour.
1 partiellement installés ou enlevés.
Après cette opération, 0 o d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.
Souhaitez-vous continuer [O/n] ? O
Paramétrage de redmine (2.3.1-1) ...
dbconfig-common: writing config to /etc/dbconfig-common/redmine/instances/default.conf

Creating config file /etc/redmine/default/database.yml.new with new version
granting access to database redmine_default for redmine@localhost: already exists.
creating database redmine_default: already exists.
dbconfig-common: flushing administrative password
rake aborted!
ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task'     
(available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead.

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
dpkg: erreur de traitement de redmine (--configure) :
le sous-processus script post-installation installé a retourné une erreur de sortie 
d'état 1

Aucun rapport « apport » écrit car MaxReports a déjà été atteint
Des erreurs ont été rencontrées pendant l'exécution :
redmine
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Little more informations below :

gem 1.8.24
Rails 3.2.13

Thanks in advance for your reply and help!

Comment: please exec the command again with `LANG=C aptitude install`, so the messages will be in english

Comment: Is your system fully up-to-date?

Comment: Yes, my system is fully up-to-date. This is the first thing I've done before preparing the installation of Redmine.

Comment: What's the ubuntu version?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known bug.
Please check https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/redmine/+bug/1249334.

You could try to download(http://packages.ubunutu.com) and install (`dpkg -i`) another version of the package, as long as it fits in your "dependency tree".

Also you could change your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and comment the lines for your current ubuntu distribution, and add another entry with a newer/older ubuntu distro.
Then exec:

```
aptitude update
aptitude install redmine redmine-mysql
```